# Access files using QFtp on a TLS service

Tags: ftp, qt4, ssl

I am writting a client using Qt and the QFtp class to retrieve files from an FTP service. The FTP service requires the use of a TLS connection. Where can I set the QFtp object to use TLS? I've already attempted to use the direct raw command retrieved from an FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

For SSL / TLS connections u should using QSslSocket instead of QTcpSocket.

Comment: I'm not using QTcpSocket, I'm using QFtp. Is there a way to tell QFtp to use QSslSocket, or do I have to initiate all the FTP commands using QSslSocket?